# Как переписать данный код в бинарном режиме?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно построчно записать в файл .txt рандомные числа в таком количестве, что б файл весил не меньше 1 Гб, вот данный код, помогите переписать в бинарном режиме

```
import random

size = 0
with open("input.txt", "w") as file:
    while True:
        s = str(random.randrange(-100,100))
        if size + len(s) + 2 < 1024 * 1024 * 1024:
            print(s, file=file)
            size += len(s) + 2
        else:
            print(' '*(1024 * 1024 * 1024 - size), file=file, end = '')
            break
```

в бинарном режиме, то есть запись вместо "w" будет выглядить "wb", но поскольку у меня тип данных str, оно выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object cannot be str.

Comment: Поясните, что такое бинарный режим и как в нем выглядят записанные в файл данные?

Comment: @Kromster, внес изменения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file.write((s + os.linesep).encode('utf-8'))
```

и

```
file.write(b' '*(1024 * 1024 * 1024 - size))
```

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev исправил, выдает ошибку TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Остается правда загадкой, зачем автору вопроса такая замена - результат все равно тот же будет, как при записи в текстовом режиме)

Comment: @Bohdan в моём ответе нет именованных аргументов. Видимо, исправили не так.

Comment: @insolor мне нужно будет применить эти значения для алгоритма многофазной сортировки, а при моем варианте, заполнение файла .txt занимает около 15 минут, а в битовом режиме быстродействие будет гораздо лучше, оперативная память не будет так нагружена

Comment: @Bohdan помогло в итоге? Мне кажется что тут без разницы каким способом писать в файл, но могу ошибаться, конечно же.